# Using reduceRight to remove last element in Array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a method to add a new list of dates that a User can request time off from work. Now I am trying to implement a way for the user to remove a date list starting from the bottom and working their way up as necessary but always keeping the first date there. Any suggestions would be appreciated

Here is the code I have for the 2 methods.

```
  dates = [1]

  onAddClicked() {
    this.dates.push(1);
  }

  onRemoveClicked() {
    this.dates.reduceRight(this.onAddClicked,);
  }
```

Here is the html for the buttons

```
<div class=modButtons>
                <button (click)="onAddClicked()" mat-raised-button color="primary">Add Dates+</button>
                <button (click)="onRemoveClicked()" mat-raised-button color="primary">Remove Dates-</button>            
            </div>
```

The error Im getting is

```
Argument of type '() => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(previousValue: number, currentValue: number, currentIndex: number, array: number[]) => number'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'number'
```

[Fields for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KH3r6.png)

Comment: Wouldn't be enough to use `this.dates.pop()` ?

Comment: @DominikMatis .pop works but it gets rid of the inital element aswell

Comment: @yabs no, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
this.dates.pop();
```

if you also want to save that element, assign the result of `pop()` to some variable :)

Well, if you don't want to remove all, then do some magic like

```
if(this.dates.length > 1) this.dates.pop();
```

Comment: Glad to help :) Please mark it as correct answer :) Have a nice day))